# Ignore javascript/jquery errors (function doesn't exist)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove Jquery-ui for a moment.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>`

But by doing that, i have a problem with `$(whatever).tabs();` `$(whatever).button();` etc...

When the browser meet the call, it just crash.

Is there a way to just ask him to continue normally ?

I don't want to add `//` manually on every lines.

Comment: `Javascript want me to manually remove all function calls` what does that mean?

Comment: Can you provide some code? Perhaps you're making a variable null/empty and thats causing problems with something expecting that value to be there. We can't help with out some more information

Comment: Sounds like you want a lazy hack for an error. Always best to fix the problem. Post some code and the error message, might be easier to fix than you think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I skip or ignore errors in javascript / jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096581/how-do-i-skip-or-ignore-errors-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: I don't want to fix anything, i want to remove JQUERY UI for testing purposes, i don't want to comment all lines with .buttons, .tabs.... I can spend hours going through a crazy amount of lines (and adding //) but that doesn't seem very clever.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap part of your code, which works with this function into `try {} catch {}`, also you could

```
window.onerror = function(){
   return true;
}
```