# Is there a way to try/catch any JS noise coming from a given <script> tag

Tags: javascript, dom, error-handling, runtime-error

I have the situation where error[s](https://my.trackjs.com/details/de1435602995425fafdb342ecbb83428#stack) are often emitted from 3rd-party JS, like Chartbeat, etc.  I want to catch and discard/mute these errors, and related noise.

All such 3rd party scripts do some variant of:

- create `<script>` DOM tag
- set attrs for source, etc.
- append it to `window`
- optionally: rewrite or hook `window.onload` to call an initializer

e.g.

```
function loadChartbeat() {
  window._sf_endpt=(new Date()).getTime();
  var e = document.createElement('script');
  e.setAttribute('language', 'javascript');
  e.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  e.setAttribute('src', '//static.chartbeat.com/js/chartbeat.js');
  document.body.appendChild(e);
}
```

How can I `try/catch` errors in this context?

Is there another way to avoid the bubbling-up of errors, when dealing with a `<script>` tag / load of this pattern?

---

I tried to add a muting function, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25875511/263858):

```
function stoperror() {
  return true;
}
function loadChartbeat() {
  window._sf_endpt=(new Date()).getTime();
  var e = document.createElement('script');
  e.setAttribute('language', 'javascript');
  e.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  e.setAttribute('src', '//static.chartbeat.com/js/chartbeat.js');
  e.onerror = stoperror;
  document.body.appendChild(e);
}
```

But the errors continue to bubble-up.

Comment: every answer will contain eval wich is evil in that context. Any way of wrapping the code somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add it serverside. Sth like that:

```
//loadscript.php
<?php
echo "try{";
readfile($_GET["url"]);//bad style, may improve it
echo "}catch(e){}";
?>
```

On userside it will get a mess, concerning security + usability. May do sth like that:

```
[...document.getElementsByTagName("script")].forEach(function(el){
 var url=el.src;
 el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
 ajax(url,function(code){ // needs to be implemented
     try{
       eval(code);
     }catch(e){}
  });
});
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but I'd guess the reason is because I don't control the serverside — which was implicit from stating that this is a 3rd-party loader.  Your solution can never be implemented.

Comment: @NewAlexandria if you use curl it also works for third parties. Not optimal, but the only solution i know...