# What happens if you pass in an invalid widgetvar?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm wondering what happens when an invalid widgetvar is passed into primefaces. I know it causes problems, but I'm wondering if there is a defined behavior/expected outcome.

A trivial example: say we have a dialog:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="dialogVar" header="Test">
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="Test"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Close Dialog" onclick="PF('badInput').hide();" immediate="true"/>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

What does Primefaces do when the 'Close Dialog' button is clicked? (assuming no other object has 'badInput' as a widgetvar)

Comment: @Kukeltje I have tried it. I've experienced it. I know it messes up the web page, but I'm looking for a specific explanation of what primefaces actually does with the bad variable.

Comment: Also, why the downvotes? I'm assuming one is from @Kukeltje, who clearly didn't understand what I was asking.

Comment: @Kukeltje If I knew how to do that, I wouldn't have asked my question. Care to explain at all? I saw nothing in the log file indicating what was going on in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrimeFaces won't "do" anything when you use an incorrect widget var. `PF('badInput')` will return `undefined`, which causes `.hide()` to fail. This is pure JavaScript and has nothing to do with PrimeFaces. When your browser encounters a JavaScript error, JavaScript execution is stopt. So you better make sure your widget exists or check it first.

You could simply check for `undefined`:

```
function hideDialog(widgetVar) {
    if (PF(widgetVar) !== undefined) {
        PF(widgetVar).hide();
    }
}
```

or use `try` and `catch`:

```
function hideDialog(widgetVar) {
    try {
        PF(widgetVar).hide();
    }
    catch (error) {
        // console.log("Caught error: " + error);
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Ignore javascript syntax errors in a page and continue executing the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219154/ignore-javascript-syntax-errors-in-a-page-and-continue-executing-the-script)

Comment: Great answer! This is exactly what I was hoping to find out, thanks!

Comment: @Kukeltje It would have taken you less time to leave a good answer then to leave a bunch of salty comments about this being 'very easy' to find out. I didn't know the answer, nor did I know how to find it, which is why I asked a question. Just because you know how to do something does not mean I do. This is why StackOverflow was created.

Comment: @Kukeltje If you have time to leave multiple, unhelpful comments, you have time to put together a short answer either giving a direct answer or giving the steps to find the answer. You don't have to spend your time on this site patrolling for people who know less than you in a certain subject to belittle them.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me with Primefaces 7.0:

```js
if (PrimeFaces.widgets['yourWidget'] !== undefined) {
    // do stuff
}
```